# Pause an addEventListener event

Tags: javascript

I have the following add event listener triggered when a user click to follow other user in my app. The problem now is that is user clicks multiple times in a row to follow, multiple notifications will be created, therefore spamming that user. What is it possible to do here, as I would not like remove follow button listener with a `removeEventListener()`, but rather pause it for some moments, and then send the notification?

```
          let userReference = await firebase
             .firestore()
             .collection("users")
             .doc(userId);

          followButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log("You started following " + userId);

            userReference
              .update({
                followers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                  user.displayName
                ),
              })
              .then(() => {
                // updated followers count
                getUserDetails();
              })
              .then(() => {
                firebase
                  .firestore()
                  .collection("notifications")
                  .doc(userId)
                  .collection("notifications")
                  .add({
                    action: "followed you",
                    userPhoto: user.photoURL,
                    from: user.displayName,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                  })
                  .then((reference) => {
                    console.log("Successfuly added notification " + reference);
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better user experience if you simply disabled the button after they click? After all, you can't follow the same person more than once, right?

Comment: As @kmoser mensioned: `followButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) { e.target.disabled = true;`

Comment: As far as I know, you can't pause event listeners. Why don't you set a flag variable after user's click? Anyway, you can also disable button using CSS only (pointer-events: none;).

Comment: `once`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters)

Comment: This might potentially be helpful: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/how-to-pause-and-resume-event-propagation-in-javascript/